# Installing Xorg on ASRock AM1H-ITX (Xen DomU Arch-Linux LXQT): startx and no screens

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, lxde, xen, pci

Dom0: Arch Linux

DomU: Arch Linux

The problem seems to be that the DomU can't find the Video Card.

inxi -F (DomU)

```
System:    Host: ArkOS_Dev Kernel: 4.2.5-1-ARCH x86_64 (64 bit) Console: tty 0 Distro: Arch Linux
Machine:   No /sys/class/dmi; using dmidecode: dmidecode is not installed.
CPU:       Single core AMD Athlon 5350 APU with Radeon R3 (-) cache: 2048 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 2050 MHz 1: 2050 MHz 2: 2050 MHz 3: 2050 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Failed to Detect Video Card!
           Display Server: N/A drivers: i128,sis,voodoo,fbdev,ati,ark,glint,nv,mach64,neomagic,vesa,savage,vmware,trident,radeon,s3,siliconmotion,intel,tdfx,nouveau,openchrome
           tty size: 151x38 Advanced Data: N/A out of X
Network:   Card: Failed to Detect Network Card!
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 95.9GB (2.8% used) ID-1: /dev/xvda model: N/A size: 93.7GB
           ID-2: /dev/xvdb model: N/A size: 2.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 86G used: 2.6G (4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/xvda
Sensors:   None detected - is lm-sensors installed and configured?
Info:      Processes: 70 Uptime: 1 min Memory: 49.8/1997.5MB Init: systemd Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.2.28
```

inxi -F (Dom0)

```
System:    Host: hypervisor Kernel: 4.2.5-1-ARCH x86_64 (64 bit) Console: tty 0 Distro: Arch Linux
Machine:   Mobo: ASRock model: AM1H-ITX Bios: American Megatrends v: P1.20 date: 09/23/2014
CPU:       Single core AMD Athlon 5350 APU with Radeon R3 (-UP-) cache: 2048 KB speed: 2050 MHz (max)
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8400 / R3 Series]
           Display Server: N/A driver: N/A tty size: 151x38 Advanced Data: N/A out of X
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.2.5-1-ARCH
Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller driver: r8169
           IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: d0:50:99:4b:96:e1
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 120.0GB (6.5% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: OCZ size: 120.0GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 16G used: 5.3G (34%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/sda2
           ID-2: /boot size: 511M used: 40M (8%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/sda1
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 2.15GB used: 0.01GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda4
Sensors:   None detected - is lm-sensors installed and configured?
Info:      Processes: 108 Uptime: 0 min Memory: 97.9/927.4MB Init: systemd Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.2.28
```

/etc/xen/Arkos-Dev_PV.cfg

```
name = 'ArkOS_Dev'
bootloader = "pygrub"
#kernel = "/mnt/arch/boot/x86_64/vmlinuz"
#ramdisk = "/mnt/arch/boot/x86_64/archiso.img"
#extra = "archisobasedir=arch archisolabel=ARCH_201511"
memory = 2048
vcpus = 3
disk = [ "format=raw, vdev=xvda, access=rw, target=/dev/vm_volumes/root.ArkOS_Dev",
         "format=raw, vdev=xvdb, access=rw, target=/dev/vm_volumes/swap.ArkOS_Dev"
       ]
vif = [ 'mac=00:16:3e:49:2b:a1,bridge=xenbr0' ]
root = "/dev/xvda rw"
```

lspci -v | grep VGA (Dom0)

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8400 / R3 Series] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

sudo xl pci-attach 0 '00:01.0,permissable=1' (Dom0)

```
Unknown PCI BDF option: permissablelibxl: error: libxl_pci.c:1105:libxl__device_pci_add: PCI device 0:0:1.0 is not assignable
```

/etc/mkinit.conf (DomU)

```
# vim:set ft=sh
# MODULES
# The following modules are loaded before any boot hooks are
# run.  Advanced users may wish to specify all system modules
# in this array.  For instance:
#     MODULES="piix ide_disk reiserfs"
MODULES="xen-blkfront xen-fbfront xen-netfront xen-kbdfront"

# BINARIES
# This setting includes any additional binaries a given user may
# wish into the CPIO image.  This is run last, so it may be used to
# override the actual binaries included by a given hook
# BINARIES are dependency parsed, so you may safely ignore libraries
BINARIES=""

# FILES
# This setting is similar to BINARIES above, however, files are added
# as-is and are not parsed in any way.  This is useful for config files.
FILES=""

# HOOKS
# This is the most important setting in this file.  The HOOKS control the
# modules and scripts added to the image, and what happens at boot time.
# Order is important, and it is recommended that you do not change the
# order in which HOOKS are added.  Run 'mkinitcpio -H <hook name>' for
# help on a given hook.
# 'base' is _required_ unless you know precisely what you are doing.
# 'udev' is _required_ in order to automatically load modules
# 'filesystems' is _required_ unless you specify your fs modules in MODULES
# Examples:
##   This setup specifies all modules in the MODULES setting above.
##   No raid, lvm2, or encrypted root is needed.
#    HOOKS="base"
#
##   This setup will autodetect all modules for your system and should
##   work as a sane default
#    HOOKS="base udev autodetect block filesystems"
#
##   This setup will generate a 'full' image which supports most systems.
##   No autodetection is done.
#    HOOKS="base udev block filesystems"
#
##   This setup assembles a pata mdadm array with an encrypted root FS.
##   Note: See 'mkinitcpio -H mdadm' for more information on raid devices.
#    HOOKS="base udev block mdadm encrypt filesystems"
#
##   This setup loads an lvm2 volume group on a usb device.
#    HOOKS="base udev block lvm2 filesystems"
#
##   NOTE: If you have /usr on a separate partition, you MUST include the
#    usr, fsck and shutdown hooks.
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block filesystems keyboard fsck"

# COMPRESSION
# Use this to compress the initramfs image. By default, gzip compression
# is used. Use 'cat' to create an uncompressed image.
#COMPRESSION="gzip"
#COMPRESSION="bzip2"
#COMPRESSION="lzma"
#COMPRESSION="xz"
#COMPRESSION="lzop"
#COMPRESSION="lz4"

# COMPRESSION_OPTIONS
# Additional options for the compressor
#COMPRESSION_OPTIONS=""
```

Comment: Is your DomU a PV or a HVM? Are you trying any sort of VGA pass through? How are you expecting to see the screen (e.g., did you enable the vnc viewer)?

Comment: PV. No. I don't know what a VGA pass through is. I just I would just see the screen? And yes, I'd eventually use remmina from another computer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I'll be going down this path too. I just acquired an AMD Athlon 5150 system, myself (Athlon 5150 with integrated Radeon HD 8400 graphics). I can't speak to Dom0/DomU being Arch Linux, but for straight Debian it looks like this is a solution:

```
    AMD/ATI Proprietary Driver
    https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary
```

Googling "AMD/ATI Proprietary Driver" and "Arch Linux" yields these two promising pages:

```
    AMD Catalyst - ArchWiki - Arch Linux
    https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMD_Catalyst

    ATI - ArchWiki
    https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI
```

Comment: AMD_Catalyst failed me so far. Trying out the open source drivers.

Comment: Same problem :( . They seem to only support older drivers.